# what is the difference between multiple select and single select Query

Tags: php, mysql

I like to know difference between multiple and single select Query

single Query

```
SELECT name,age,country FROM user
```

Multiple Query

```
SELECT name FROM user 
SELECT age FROM user 
SELECT country FROM user
```

I am having functions to get values for each column in user table... That why this question 
arises.. This may be silly but i like to know

Comment: ha ha ha ... sometime my mind is witch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second query is pointless. It would be more worthwhile explaining the difference if it's a UNION join:

```
(SELECT name FROM user) UNION
(SELECT age FROM user) UNION
(SELECT country FROM user)
```

**Difference?** It takes longer for no real gain or reason. **Pointless again.**

```
SELECT name, age, country FROM user
```

This is **ineffective** as well. You should only select data you want, this selects for ALL users -- bad bad bad.

---

### A better way to optimize a query

```
SELECT name, age, country FROM user WHERE username IN ('gary', 'john')
```

Select only the data you want. Don't:

- **don't:** `SELECT *`
- **don't:** select all record
- **don't**: do multiple selects that are pointless.

**DO:** think logically about your data, what information you really want. Always use the `EXPLAIN` query to get a real idea of the performance of each query.

Comment: did you read my question ? Mr green all is well ... But my question is different... i am having functions for each column like get_user_name($id),get_user_country($id) and etc ... some time i am only looking to get country only in that case i will use it... suppose i use the three functions in same page, is this good or bad.. bad means y

Comment: Across your whole page you just get one piece of information i.e. country, that's it? I find that hard to believe. Your best bet is to create a `User` class that will get all the fields you want, cache them so they can be output anywhere you like across your pages. You interact with this class i.e. `$user->get('country, age')` -- this is a nice pattern because that way you can add easily add filters onto it, using an Active Record Pattern: `$user->limit(3)->country('uk')->get('username')` it's fairly straight forward creating such a class.

Answer (score 4):

In the first case you'll go to the grocery 1 time and back to home with a big bag, in the second case you'll go to the grocery 3 times and back to home with a small bag. If your are late you should prefere the first way...

Answer (score 1):

In the first example you get all the data you need in a single query, whereas in the second you'll have to do three queries (this is bad) and get three different datasets.

Answer (score 1):

Exactly what it looks like.

With a single query you get everything in one go.

With multiple queries you get one thing. Then you ask for another thing and get that. Then you ask for another thing and get that.

i.e. asking three separate times is slow and wasteful and will, when computers get sentience, result in unhappy robots beating you up.

Answer (score 0):

Why you'd want to run three queries with statically defined column headers, instead of picking out:

```
SELECT name, age, country FROM user
```

Is beyond me!

Unions are useful if you have two tables with the same table structure, but definitely not needed for this case.